# why is a destructor IMPLICITLY called twice on same object?

Tags: c++, destructor

Consider the following snippet of c++ and the output below it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class One {
public:
    One(int num);
    One();
    ~One();
private:
    int number;
};

One::One(int num) {
    number = num;
    cout << "One constructor number = " << number << endl;
}

One::One() {
    number = 0;
    cout << "default One constructor\n";
}

One::~One() {
    cout << "One destructor. number = " << number << endl;
    number = 0;
}

int main() {
    One uno;
    uno = One(2);
    return 0;
}
```

default One constructor

One constructor number = 2

One destructor. number = 2

One destructor. number = 2

Notice the replication of the last line. I understand (& hate) why the default constructor is called by the first line in main, but the destructor for that instance is never called. Instead the destructor for the second instance is implicitly called twice. Why? And how is the variable 'number' able to persist at number=2 ? The destructor set it to 0. It's like the garbage collector is  trying to delete the instance created by the default constructor but hitting an old copy of the 2nd.  This is a trivial example but it's a real problem when it comes time to delete pointers.

Comment: The simple solution is to not use raw pointers for ownership. And if you want to see which object is destructed, print `this` and not some data member that gets copied around when you make copies of the class. Finally, C++ doesn't have a garbage collector. Destructors are run at the end of the object's scope and the object's memory is cleaned up after that.

Comment: You've created two `One` objects. Both are destructed individually. `uno`'s `number` has been changed because you assigned it a new value (2), so now it's printing out the same message as the temporary object's deconstructor. And C++ has no garbage collector, FYI.

Comment: What does it mean to not use raw pointers for ownership (are there cooked pointers that are better suited to ownership)

Answer (score 7):

```
One uno;   // Create a default One instance - default constructor called.
uno = One(2); // Create a temporary One instance - number constructor called and prints 2.
              // Assign temporary to uno - uno now has the number 2.
              // Destroy temporary One instance - destructor called and prints 2.
return 0;
// uno destroyed. It has the number 2, so this also prints 2.
```

Or, in terms of the output you saw:

```
default One constructor // from uno construction
One constructor number = 2 // from temporary One(2) construction
One destructor. number = 2 // from temporary One(2) destruction
One destructor. number = 2 // from uno destruction (since number has changed)
```

Comment: But if the temporary object is assigned to uno, why isn't uno's number value set to 0 when the temporary object is destroyed? number=0 is in the destructor.

Comment: The temporary is destroyed after the copy assignment, not before. Thus the value of the number is copied from the temporary before it is set to zero.

Comment: So by "assign to" do you mean copy to? Not like a reference is assigned to a variable.

Comment: "copy assignment" is the term for an assignment statement of the form `x = y` that invokes a copy.

Comment: OK. How do I avoid this situation when "One uno(2)" is not an option? The real application has pointers. The program seg faults or worse when I try to delete my pointers in the destructor. and apparently seg faults are not caught by try catch exception handlers.

Comment: You clearly do not have a functional copy assignment operator. That should be your first priority. Keep the rule of three/five in mind at all times.